# Import not working in Netbeans JAVA 8.1 Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, netbeans, import, symbols

New to JAVA and Netbeans

My problem is that when I try to call a method from another class I get error:
"Cannot find symbol"

I do have import in calling class and tried every variation I could think of but the same error continues.

I copied the method into the calling class and the error disappears, but this is not useful since many classes will need to call this function.

Here are the specifics:

Created a test method in:

Calculators
|--Source Packages
   |--schmidtjts.com.calculators
      |--Functions_Conversion.java

```
package schmidtjts.com.calculators;

public class Functions_Conversion {
        public static int test_lf(int Input) {
        return Input * 10;
    }
)
```

And then try to call it in:

Calculators
|--Source Packages
   |--schmidtjts.com.calculators.ui.pages
      |--Displacement.java

```
package schmidtjts.com.calculators.ui.pages;

import schmidtjts.com.calculators.Functions_Conversion;

public class Displacement extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public Displacement() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void testMethod() { 
        double ttt = test_lf(1);  
    }
}
```

I hope someone will have an idea, I have searched many problems with similar descriptions but not found a solution.
Tried deleting cache and restarting Netbeans.

Comment: "test_lf" is the symbol/method that cannot be found.

Comment: please look for **objects**. In that way, you can call the method anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Your code should look like this:

```
package schmidtjts.com.calculators.ui.pages;

//This import below isn't that relevant.
import schmidtjts.com.calculators.Functions_Conversion;

public class Displacement extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public Displacement() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void testMethod() { 
         //Initialize an object that can be used to call the method 
         Functions_Conversion myObject = new Functions_Conversion();

        //Then call the method using the object you've just created
         myObject.test_If(1);  
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Try initializing an **object** like this:

```
//Initialize an object that can be used to call the method 
Functions_Conversion myObject = new Functions_Conversion();

//Then call the method using the object you've just created
myObject.test_If(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestion. 
Unfortunately the "test_If" is still underlined in red with the error "cannot find symbol.